# Is there any way to deploy a React app to GCP Bucket via Gitlab CI?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-storage, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a React App to google cloud plataform Buckets via Gitlab CI and i was wondering if there is a simple way to do it. In this moment i'm deploying manually from the project with the command `npm build myapp --prod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's not very difficult. you need

- A service account key file that you store in your Pipeline secret
- A step where you load the [gcloud SDK container](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/)

  - Load the key and save it in local file
  - Perform a `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<local file>`
  - Perform a `gsutil -m cp <your source file dir>/* gs://<your bucket>`

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked!